# Image list of 3D-arrays to one 4D-array

Tags: r

I have an image list of 3D-arrays with dimensions width x height x channels. Now I want to convert this list within R into a single 4D-array with the dimensions length_of_list x width x height x channels.

The following R-Code works fine, but I think there's a more efficient solution:

```
# Settings
img_width <- 200
img_height <- 100
img_channels <- 3

# Preallocate multidimensional array
marray <- array(NA, dim = c(length(imagelist), img_width, img_height, img_channels))

# Transfer data to array
for (i in 1:length(imagelist)) {
  img <- imagelist[[i]]
  marray[i,,,] <- img
}
```

Thanks in advance!